# Using Javascript with Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, safari

Hi I have a rather unusual problem I am creating a website that uses a payment gateway, I have provided a quantity field on the order page although there is a quantity field provided by the script provided by the payment gateway company. What I wanted was to have all the fields on one page, and then use cookies to copy and paste the quantity entered into Payment Gateway field (which is on a different page. Here is is my code to retrieve the cookie and paste it into the Quantity field on the gateway page:

```
<script>
        function ReadCookie()
        {
           var allcookies = document.cookie;
           //document.write ("All Cookies : " + allcookies );

           // Get all the cookies pairs in an array
           cookiearray = allcookies.split(';');

           // Now take key value pair out of this array
           for(var i=0; i<cookiearray.length; i++){
              name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
              val = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
              //alert(val);
              //document.write ("Key is : " + name + " and Value is : " + value);
              document.getElementById("qty").value = val;
           }
        }
</script>
```

And here is the script provided by the payment gateway:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        function click_a15a0ae39a4f7743373515e1d658d1c7(aform_reference) {
            var aform = aform_reference;
            aform['amount'].value = Math.round(aform['amount'].value * Math.pow(10, 2)) / Math.pow(10, 2);
            aform['custom_quantity'].value = aform['custom_quantity'].value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
            if (!aform['custom_quantity'].value || 0 === aform['custom_quantity'].value.length || /^\s*$/.test(aform['custom_quantity'].value)) {
                alert('A quantity is required');
                return false;
            } aform['amount'].value *= parseInt(aform['custom_quantity'].value);
        }
</script>
<form action="https://www.payfast.co.za/eng/process" name="form_a15a0ae39a4f7743373515e1d658d1c7" onsubmit="return click_a15a0ae39a4f7743373515e1d658d1c7( this );" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_paynow">
    <input type="hidden" name="receiver" value="10479125">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Rubydrops">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="219.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_description" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="http://www.rubydrops.co.za/_confirmation_contact.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="http://www.rubydrops.co.za/_order_cancellation.html">
    <table style="width:90%;margin:0.5em auto;">
        <tr><td align="right"><font color="red">*</font>&nbsp;<b>Quantity</b></td><td><input type="text" name="custom_quantity" id="qty" value="1"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2 align=center><input type="image" src="https://www.payfast.co.za/images/buttons/light-small-buynow.png" width="165" height="36" alt="Buy Now" title="Buy Now with  PayFast"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I normally use Firefox as my default browser, when I tested the above I kept getting some random number added into the Quantity field on the Gateway page, then I discovered that this problem only occurs when using Firefox, I tried again with Chrome, IE11, Edge and Safari. All worked. Then I tested it on Safari for iPhone same problem as Firefox, same problem occurs in the default Android browser as well as Chrome for Android.

Can anyone tell what the problem is and how to rectify it on the offending browsers, if you want to check yourself, I have set up the website in a temporary location here http://www.thetaware.co.za/Demo_three/orders.php

Help would be appreciated.
Ian

Comment: Did you clear your cookies before testing ? It works fine for me in desktop FF (latest). The JS you show doesn't look like it would have cross-browser issues.

Comment: I also have the latest FF, how would clearing cookies help, I put an alert in my script to see if the cookie found correctly, it does and while the alert is up the correct figure appears, then is overwritten when I acknowledge the alert. I will admit this is the first time I've used cookies and so am not familiar completely with how they work although from what I have studied so far they a re quite simple. However, I will try doing that.

Comment: I tried deleting all cookies before testing, still makes no difference, still get the random number appearing in the Quantity input box, does anyone else have any ideas why this should occur and why only on certain browsers.